# filling in missing data in one data frame with info from another

Tags: r, missing-data

There are two data set, A & B, as below:

```
A <- data.frame(TICKER=c("00EY","00EY","00EY","00EY","00EY"), 
                CUSIP=c(NA,NA,"48205A10","48205A10","48205A10"), 
                OFTIC=c(NA,NA,"JUNO","JUNO","JUNO"), 
                CNAME=c(NA,NA, "JUNO", "JUNO","JUNO"), 
                ANNDATS=c("2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13"),
                ANALYS=c(00076659,00105887,00153117,00148921,00086659),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- data.frame(TICKER=c("00EY","00EY","00EY","00EY"), 
                CUSIP=c("48205A10","48205A10","48205A10","48205A10"),
                OFTIC=c("JUNO","JUNO",NA,NA), 
                CNAME=c("JUNO","JUNO", NA, NA), 
                ANNDATS=c("2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13"), 
                ANALYS=c(00076659,00105887,00153117,00148921), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

How can I fill in missing data in one data frame with info from another? (A & B data sets are not of the same length).

Comment: There are errors in your sample data, I cannot run them in R. (Missing " around strings, and ANALYS contains a `.` instead of a `,`.) Also consider, using other sample data, since in this case B is already your expected result.

Comment: Yes,  in this case, B is already my expected a result. But sample data B is a part of my B data set. I just fetched a part of it. The trouble is that these two databases have incomplete information on each other.

Comment: A=data.frame(TICKER=c("00EY","00EY","00EY","00EY"), CUSIP=c(NA,NA,"48205A10","48205A10"), OFTIC=c(NA,NA,"JUNO","JUNO"), CNAME=c(NA,NA, "JUNO", "JUNO"), ANNDATS=c("2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13"), ANALYS=c(00076659,00105887,00153117,00148921), stringsAsFactors = F)

Comment: Thanks for Florian. I change A & B data set already. thank you

Comment: Please make sure to include all important information about your problem. As it stands you have 2 identical data frames with different values missing

Comment: ok. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, now what happens If `A$CNAME[5]` is `NA`? What do you replace it with? you leave it NA?

Comment: Sorry Sotos, I will make sure my problems next time. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Now, ANALYS has the same code in one data set, what can we do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill up missing values using the other data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938081/fill-up-missing-values-using-the-other-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the two data sets can have different lengths, you need some feature which they can be connected by. As it seems `ANALYS` is some kind of identifier, we can use it to connect the two data.frames in this example.

First we identify all missings in `df1` (i.e. `A`) and acquire their indices (rows and cols).
Then, the missings in `df1` are subsituted by the values in `df2` corresponding to the line with the same value of `ANALYS`. If this ID is not available in df2, the line will be skipped.

```
f <- function(df1, df2){
  missings <- sapply(df1, is.na)
  missingsInd <- which(missings, arr.ind = T)

  for(i in 1:nrow(missingsInd)){
    idOfMissing <- df1$ANALYS[missingsInd[i,1]]
    correspondingLine <- df2[which(df2$ANALYS == idOfMissing), ]
    if (nrow(correspondingLine) != 0) {
      df1[missingsInd[i,1], missingsInd[i,2]] <-  correspondingLine[1,missingsInd[i,2]]
    }
  }
  df1
}
f(A, B)
#   TICKER    CUSIP OFTIC CNAME    ANNDATS ANALYS IRECCD
# 1   00EY 48205A10  JUNO  JUNO 2015-01-13  76659      1
# 2   00EY 48205A10  JUNO  JUNO 2015-01-13 105887      2
# 3   00EY 48205A10  JUNO  JUNO 2015-01-13 153117      1
# 4   00EY 48205A10  JUNO  JUNO 2015-01-13 148921      3
# 5   00EY 48205A10  JUNO  JUNO 2015-01-13  86659      4
```

*Note* that cells with `NA`s within both data.frames will return as `NA` as in the output. Furthermore, this only applies if ANALYS only holds unique values within both data.frames.

Comment: loki, Thanks for the help.  Can I further extend the problem?

Comment: Now, ANALYS has the same code in one data set, what can we do?

Comment: I will spend the time to understand the answer is.

Comment: Hi, I look my data. I have a question if no variables hold unique values within both data. What should we do?

Comment: Do you have any matching columns?