# Fill up missing values using the other data?

Tags: r, missing-data

```
A <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", "00FR"),  
                Item_B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "JAMES RIVER", NA, NA))

B <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", "00FR"), 
                Item_B = c("JAMES RIVER", NA, "JAMES RIVER",
                           "RICE MIDSTREAM", "RICE MIDSTREAM"))
```

Expected:

```
A <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", "00FR"),  
                Item_B = c("JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", 
                         "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "RICE MIDSTREAM", "RICE MIDSTREAM"))

B <- data.frame(Item_A = c("00EF", "00EF", "00EF", "00FR", "00FR"), 
                Item_B = c("JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", "JAMES RIVER", 
                           "RICE MIDSTREAM", "RICE MIDSTREAM"))
```

I have to fill in item `Item_B` according to the `Item_B` of other rows where `Item_A` is the same. For example, the first to fourth observation of `Item_B` in data set `A` need to become "JAMES RIVER".

Can you please suggest a way to fill in the missing values in R? I tried many techniques but couldn't get what I wanted.

Comment: `zoo::na.locf(A$Item_B, fromLast = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: ok, Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have understood the question, this is *not* just an exercise to simply filling up missing values in one column of each data.frame. I believe this requires to fill in the values of `Item_B` which belong to `Item_A` with help of a look up or mapping table:

```
library(data.table)
# create mapping table from both data.frames
map <- unique(rbindlist(list(A, B)))[!is.na(Item_B)]
# or, in case there are additional columns besides Item_A and Item_B
map <- unique(rbindlist(list(A, B))[!is.na(Item_B), .(Item_A, Item_B)])
map
```

> ```
>    Item_A         Item_B
> 1:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 2:   00EF    JAMES RIVER
> 3:   00FR RICE MIDSTREAM
> ```

```
# join and replace
setDT(A)[map, on = c("Item_A"), Item_B := i.Item_B][]
```

> ```
>    Item_A         Item_B
> 1:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 2:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 3:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 4:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 5:   00FF    JAMES RIVER
> 6:   00FR RICE MIDSTREAM
> 7:   00FR RICE MIDSTREAM
> ```

```
setDT(B)[map, on = c("Item_A"), Item_B := i.Item_B][]
```

> ```
>    Item_A         Item_B
> 1:   00EF    JAMES RIVER
> 2:   00EF    JAMES RIVER
> 3:   00EF    JAMES RIVER
> 4:   00FR RICE MIDSTREAM
> 5:   00FR RICE MIDSTREAM
> ```

During join, there are two columns named `Item_B`, one from the first data table, `A` (or `B`, resp.) and the other from the second data table `map`. To distinguish them, the `i.` prefix indicates that `i.Item_B` should be taken from `map`.

Comment: Hi Uwe, I like your code. But I try your code, the NAs still the same in A & B data set. It can not out put the expect code like you write.

Comment: @YXCHEN Please, try again, I have corrected the code. Apparently, I have been too eager to polish the code before posting.

Comment: If you're going to `setDT` each table anyways, could do that first and use `rbind(...)` instead of `rbindlist(list(...))`

Comment: @Frank You're right, that's a viable variant. But, I had the impression that the OP might have more data.frames than just the two sample sets shown.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create a dictionnary dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
dictionnary <- bind_rows(A,B) %>% 
           filter(!is.na(Item_B)) %>% 
           distinct
find_name <- function(id){
  name <- dictionnary[["Item_B"]][which(dictionnary[["Item_A"]]==id)]
  return(name)
}
test_id <- c("00EF","00EF","00EF","00FR","00FR")
new_names <- sapply(test_id ,find_name )
```

You could then declare your dataframe :

```
New_A <- data.frame(Item_A=c("00FF","00FF","00FF","00FF","00FF","00FR","00FR"),
                Item_B=sapply(c("00FF","00FF","00FF","00FF","00FF","00FR","00FR"),find_name))

New_B <- data.frame(Item_A=c("00EF","00EF","00EF","00FR","00FR"), 
                Item_B=sapply(c("00EF","00EF","00EF","00FR","00FR"),find_name))
```

Comment: Hi Barkallah, thanks. But I used the code. It is an error. Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'new_names' not found

Comment: Thanks, i 've fixed the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try tidyr library helper `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
A %>% 
  tidyr::fill(Item_B, .direction = "down") %>% 
  tidyr::fill(Item_B, .direction = "up")

  Item_A      Item_B
1   00FF JAMES RIVER
2   00FF JAMES RIVER
3   00FF JAMES RIVER
4   00FF JAMES RIVER
5   00FF JAMES RIVER
6   00FR JAMES RIVER
7   00FR JAMES RIVER
```

Comment: Hi cephalopod, thanks. But "00FR" = ""RICE MIDSTREAM"" not "JAMES RIVER"

Answer (score 0):

@YXCHEN update based on your input

```
lookup_df <- unique(rbindlist(list(A, B)))[!is.na(Item_B)] 

left_join(A %>% select(Item_A), lookup_df)
left_join(B %>% select(Item_A), lookup_df)
```

Comment: @cephalopod Your answer is mixing functions from `data.table` and `dplyr` without mentioning the packages.